# Scan text file for line containing a given string and replace the line with another string

Tags: vb.net, file

I want to scan my file for line that contains a particular string "black=" and if there is a match replace it with "blah blah" but I don't know how to do that. Here is what I tried but it does not work.

```
Dim myStreamReaderL1 As System.IO.StreamReader
myStreamReaderL1 = System.IO.File.OpenText("C:\File.txt")
myStreamReaderL1.ReadLine()
If myStreamReaderL1.ReadLine.Contains("black=") Then
    Button2.Hide()
Else
    Return
End If
```

Comment: How big is this file?

Comment: the code you have if inside a function is going to return after reading the first line that does not contain `black =`. You need to modify the else section of that statement. Also you are only reading 2 lines. The way you have one line is read and then another line is read and checked. If you want to check the whole document you need to loop through the lines or read the whole text and then do a replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the input file is not huge, you can read the whole file into a string and change all instances of `black=` to `blah blah`

```
        Dim myStreamReaderL1 As System.IO.StreamReader
        Dim myStream As System.IO.StreamWriter

        Dim myStr As String
        myStreamReaderL1 = System.IO.File.OpenText("C:\File.txt")
        myStr = myStreamReaderL1.ReadToEnd()
        myStreamReaderL1.Close()


        myStr = myStr.Replace("black=", "blah blah")
        'Save myStr
        myStream = System.IO.File.CreateText("C:\FileOut.txt")
        myStream.WriteLine(myStr)
        myStream.Close()
```

**EDIT:** a slightly more efficient (less code) version with ReadAllText per **Christian Sauer** 's suggestion.

**EDIT2:** if I am trying to be efficient, lets optimize everything. One line is enough, me thinks.

If you want to save into a file:

```
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\FileOut.txt", System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\File.txt").Replace("black=", "blah blah"))
```

If you simply want to store into a string to be used later:

```
        Dim myStr As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\File.txt").Replace("black=", "blah blah")
```

Comment: I was trying to stick to OPs code as much as possible. I updated my answer with your suggestion. ReadAllText makes the code slightly shorter.