# Replace a certain word/string in a .txt file with another word/string. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, replace

Hmm so i think the title explains enough. Hope someone has a answer. Thanks... Pretty much all I need to do is replace a string from a text file with another one. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look [here][1] there is a good solution to do this


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572061/scan-text-file-for-line-containing-a-given-string-and-replace-the-line-with-anot

Comment: would you be pleasant and write a real answer just but this into a answer so i can say it is the rigth answer...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to rewrite the whole file if it's not *too* large:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, File.ReadAllText(path).Replace(oldText, newText))
```

If you have to replace all **words** it's a little bit more difficult. Btw, what is a word by your definition at all? Here is one approach:

```
Dim newWords = From word In File.ReadAllText(path).Split()
               Select If(word = oldWord, newWord, word)
File.WriteAllText(path, String.Join(" ", newWords))
```

Comment: Ok ill try it soon just gotta re install VB.NET, don't even ask me why i am stupid. ^^

Comment: hm just which vb are you using i am using vb 2010 and it does not work the first thing you typed at all. Also word means i got a script like this: {
  "id": "1.7.2",
  "time": "2014-04-02T12:00:00+02:00",
  "releaseTime": "2013-10-25T15:00:00+02:00",
  "type": "release", that is just a part of it. I need to replace 1.7.2 in the beginning.

Comment: @FrostyTosty: i'm also using VS 2010. Maybe you have to add `Imports System.Linq` for the second approach. According to your data:
 You should have mentioned that in your question since my approach would replace all occurences of `1.7.2`. You might want to use a real csv-parser to initialze classes with meaningful properties like `ID` and `Time` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help really much but i found that a guy has a solution, found it on a other question.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the code below... sourced on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572061/scan-text-file-for-line-containing-a-given-string-and-replace-the-line-with-anot)

```
 Dim myStreamReaderL1 As System.IO.StreamReader
        Dim myStream As System.IO.StreamWriter

        Dim myStr As String
        myStreamReaderL1 = System.IO.File.OpenText("C:\File.txt")
        myStr = myStreamReaderL1.ReadToEnd()
        myStreamReaderL1.Close()


        myStr = myStr.Replace("OldString", "New String")
        'Save myStr
        myStream = System.IO.File.CreateText("C:\FileOut.txt")
        myStream.WriteLine(myStr)
        myStream.Close()
```